# How to print each object's properties and values from viewmodel in razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to print properties of each object available in viewmodel?

**Viewmodel:**

```
public class DepartmentDetails{
    DeptProp1{get;set;}
    .
    .
}

public class ExperienceDetails{
    ExpProp1{get;set;}
    .
    .
}

public class EmployeeDetails{
    EmpProp1{get;set;}
    .
    .
}


Public class EmployeeViewModel{
    DepartmentDetails { get;set }
    ExperienceDetails { get;set; }
    EmployeeDetails { get;set; }        
}
```

**View**

```
@model DemoProject.Models.Viewmodels.EmployeeViewModel


@foreach(var property in Model.DepartmentDetails)
{
    Lable //PropertyName
    Value //PropertyValue
}

@foreach(var property in Model.ExperienceDetails)
{
    Lable //PropertyName
    Value //PropertyValue
}

@foreach(var property in Model.EmployeeDetails)
{
    Lable //PropertyName
    Value //PropertyValue
}
```

However,

- How can we get more details of each property? i.e. DataType and so on?
- In above case we know the type of each object in viewmodel. Can we extract each object in viewmodel without knowing to each object?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using reflection. The following code should work, however you should be careful while using reflection as it can lead to performance issue.

```
@foreach(var property in typeof(DepartmentDetails).GetProperties())
{
    var label = property.Name;
    var value = property.GetValue(Model.DepartmentDetails);
}
```